# Character X or of X

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning

> A: Do you know Rosa from Brooklyn Nine-Nine? (Brookyln Nine-Nine is an
>   american sitcom. Rosa is one of the character in this tv-series.)

---

> B: Of course I know ***character of Rosa***.
>
> B1: Of course I know ***character Rosa***.

Should I use B or B1 when I am trying to imply that I have watched the tv-series and I know the characters, including Rosa? Not trying to imply that I know the personal qualities of Rosa.

Comment: Normally just "Of course I know Rosa", but if you want to make explicit she's a character, not an actor: "Of course I know **the character Rosa**".

Comment: @JasonBassford Sorry. I have edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, this is not one of the special contexts where you can use a singular countable noun without an article, so you need "**the** character".

Secondly, when you are specifying something with a general term and a name, the pattern "the X of [name]" is used only for some geographical items: most commonly towns, cities, islands; for example "The city of Moscow", "the island of Malta".

For all other kinds of item, you simply use the pattern "the X [name]", for example "The book *Gone with the Wind*", "the actor Benedict Cumberbatch", "the entrepreneur Elon Musk".

So the form you want here is

> Of course I know the character Rosa.

The phrase "the character of Rosa" is grammatical, but has a different meaning: "character" here would mean "a person's basic nature". So

> Of course I know the character of Rosa (more often "Rosa's character")

means "Of course I know what kind of person Rosa is.

Comment: There's also the possibility of including a preposition *(...know **of / about** Rosa)* to explicitly indicate that you're aware of Rosa's existence, as opposed to being personally acquainted with her.